# Continuously depending a binary random variable

Tags: online-algorithms, model, binary-data

Suppose I have 2 exclusive events, and at each point in time, I maintain the probability for the first event, p (the other one being 1-p). There is online, streaming information arriving all the time, and I would like to update p with respect to this new, arriving information. This is an industry, practical problem rather than research topic. What is the simplest, most practical approach for tackling this situation?

Comment: Could you describe how the data you receive is related to the event? Also, do you expected the value of event is the correct one at any given time to change frequently in relation to the update frequency?

Comment: "most practical" will depend on how important precision is; and everything will depend on the stability of the process.  Can you give any more context?

Comment: Can we assume you mean disjoint (i.e. "mutually exclusive") when you mention the events being exclusive?

Comment: @Michael Chernick: Yes

Comment: @ Bogdanovist: This is not known. I know some event make A more likely, and some make B more likely, but I do not know by how much.

Answer (score 1):

If p is expected to be an underlying constant ratio, the simplest most practical approach to estimate it is just $\frac{\sum{x}}{n}$, where $x$ is a one for a first type of events and zero otherwise and n is the number of opportunities.

If p changes over time - and particularly in fact if any such change is exactly what you are interested in - you could try a weighted rolling average over time where $\hat{p_i}=\frac{\sum{w_ix_i}}{\sum{w}}$ where w is a variable that gets smaller as $i$ gets further in the past.  So you have a different value of $p_i$ at any time $i$, and indeed you can compare its progress over time.

Unfortunately choice of a function for $w$ seems (to me - others may know better) to be largely arbitrary and a matter for judgement.  In tourism statistics for example it seems to be really common to estimate a rolling average where w=1 for the last 12 monthly observations and zero before that; effectively using this as a cheap (but not very sensitive) form of seasonal adjustment and smoothing out irregularities (unknown whether they are real or from measurement error) in the data.

You can see that the case of $\hat{p_i}=\frac{\sum{x}}{n}$ is just a special case of $\hat{p_i}=\frac{\sum{w_ix_i}}{\sum{w}}$, but where you have given equal values to all the $w_i$.

More sophisticated models are possible if you are prepared to go into the world of time series analysis of stochastic processes; whether this is worthwhile would depend on the sort of data generating process you think you might have, and the purpose of your analysis.

Comment: Peter Ellis: I think you give a correct answer but it sounds like the OP is looking for a recursive fomrula for updating the estimate in the case of the unweighted estimate p$_n$=∑x$_i$/n the recursion would be p$_n$$_+$$_1$=n p$_n$/(n+1) + x$_n$$_+$$_1$/(n+1).